# Ошибка при авторизации (получение token)

Tags: android, retrofit2, token

Очень нужна помощь. При попытке получить token при авторизации выдает ошибку:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb7d0da80: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x83bd1770:0x00000000)
```

Ответ json должен получить

```
{
    "data": {
        "token": "AnEly3zp16_7LvKfsQCBk7"
    },
    "error": null,
    "system": {
        "time": 0.214062
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь реализовать так

```
public interface API {
    @POST("auth")
    Call<LoginResponse> login(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest);
}
```

Модель

```
public class LoginRequest {
    public LoginRequest(String login, String password) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @SerializedName("login")
    String login;

    @SerializedName("password")
    String password;
}
```

и

```
public class LoginResponse {
    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("data")
    public Data data;

    public class Data {
        @Nullable
        @SerializedName("token")
        public String token;
    }

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("error")
    public String error;

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("system")
    public System system;

    public class System {
        @Nullable
        @SerializedName("time")
        public double time;
    }
}
```

Активити

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://mysite.ru/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        API api = retrofit.create(API.class);

        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest("user", "pass");

        Call<LoginResponse> call = api.login(loginRequest);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
                if (loginResponse != null) {
                    Log.d("mData", loginResponse.data.token);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("mData", t.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Помогите что не так? 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если вы не сможете этот запрос из PostMan или `curl`-ом повторить, то ошибка на сервере. А может у вас андроид до 5 версии ОС?

Comment: Вы думаете, что в коде нет никакой ошибки? Почему Android ниже 5 версии может такую ошибку выдавать? В Postman вроде работает нормально, единственный момент, может это что-то подскажет, если забивать логин и пароль в поле `form-data`, работает без нареканий, а если в поле `raw` в виде `{
 "login" : "user"
 "password" : "pass"
}` тогда возвращает код 400

Comment: До 5 версии есть проблемы с сертификатами SSL, ошибка похожа, вот я и подумал, что оно. А код да, вроде не тот. Попробуйте вот как-то так: `@POST("/posts")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<Post> savePost(@Field("title") String title,
                        @Field("body") String body,
                        @Field("userId") long userId);` Т.е. не в теле пересылать, но отдельными параметрами + `@FormUrlEncoded` аннотация

Comment: Пробовал, не работает((

Comment: А на чём тестируете? Какой девайс? Какая версия ОС? Может таки в этом дело.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Проверьте ваш сервис бэкенда с помощью утилиты 
   https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html
   Скорее всего у вас самоподписанный сертификат или нет всей цепочки, и для свежих версий это считается источником уязвимостей man in the middle
2. Если пофиксить сертификат не получается, можно попробовать UnsafeOkHttpClient
   например так https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-trust-unsafe-ssl-certificates-self-signed-expired

Также может помочь логгирование всего вывода через OkHTTP используя https://stackoverflow.com/a/33256827/5892568 или Stetho http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

Comment: Проблема была из-за сервера api